# Call an action from View without changing Page

Tags: .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP .NET CORE 3.

I'm trying to call an action from a view using ajax but all my attemps results in a 404 error.
Here is my code :

The Action in my controller

```
[HttpGet]
    public static async Task<int> RunSelenium(string idCampagne)
    {
        SeleniumDriver seleniumInstance = new SeleniumDriver();
        Campagnes campagne = mongo.GetCampaign(idCampagne);
        seleniumInstance.startBrowser();
        seleniumInstance.Connection(campagne.user);
        //campagne.RunTask(campagne);
        return 1;
    }
```

And the view with the ajax code

```
$(".LaunchSelenium").on("click", function () {
    LaunchSelenium(this.id);
});



  function LaunchSelenium(id) {
      $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: '@Url.Action("RunSelenium", "Home")' + "?id=" + id,
          async: true,
      });
  }
```

**Thank you for reading !**

Comment: You are passing a parameter named id from ajax, but your controller is expecting idCampagne parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an ASP.NET MVC controller method to be invoked via Ajax the method should not be static as it is in Web Forms. Remove static from controller method and change the parameter name you are sending from ajax.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<int> RunSelenium(string idCampagne)
{
    SeleniumDriver seleniumInstance = new SeleniumDriver();
    Campagnes campagne = mongo.GetCampaign(idCampagne);
    seleniumInstance.startBrowser();
    seleniumInstance.Connection(campagne.user);
    //campagne.RunTask(campagne);
    return 1;
}
```

And javascript

```
$(".LaunchSelenium").on("click", function () {
    LaunchSelenium(this.id);
});

function LaunchSelenium(id) {
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: '@Url.Action("RunSelenium", "Home")' + "?idCampagne=" + id,
      async: true,
  });
}
```